# Play framework with postgresql backup - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, playframework, key, backup, duplicates

I have a problem using `postgreSQL` with `play framework`. I have a platform with a register form and sometimes it works properly but sometimes this error happens:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: 
ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: duplicate key value violates 
unique constraint "student_pkey"\n   Detail: Key (id)=(1125) already exists.]]]
```

This problem happens because I want to use a dump from another DB and play doesn't know what is the next id to use.

However, I've created `SEQUENCES(1)` and an `annotations(2)` to each primary key but it doesn't work properly.

```
1- SELECT SETVAL('student_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM "student") + 1);
2- In model Student - @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

I don't know what to do.I thought that using `SEQUENCE` and `annotations` `Play` should know what would be the next ID in the sequence and should also know what ID's are being already used!